# Multinomial Co-efficient Summation

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

If
$$
\begin{equation}
(1+x+x^2+...+x^p)^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_{np}x^{np}
\end{equation}\label{given}\tag{1}
$$

Prove that
$$
\begin{equation}
S=a_1+2a_2+3a_3+...+np.a_{np}=\frac{1}{2}np(1+p)^n 
\end{equation}\label{to_prove}\tag{2}
$$

**Note: I found the way to solve this using calculus. But I need to solve this without using calculus.**

Below is the progress I've been able to make:

Substituting $x=1$,
$$\underbrace{(1+1+1+\cdots+1)^n}_\textrm{(p+1) terms}=a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{np}$$
$$
\begin{equation}
\therefore \text{ } (1+p)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{np}a_k
\end{equation}\label{res1}\tag{3}
$$

We know,
$$(1-x)^{-2}=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+(r+1)x^r+\cdots$$
$$
\begin{equation}
\implies\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2}=1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{r+1}{x^r}+\cdots
\end{equation}\label{res2}\tag{4}
$$

Multiplying $\eqref{given}$ and $\eqref{res2}$, the co-efficient of $x^0$ on RHS would be
$$a_0+2a_1+3a_2+\cdots+(np+1)a_{np}$$
$$=(a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{np})+(a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+npa_{np})$$
$$
\begin{equation}
=(1+p)^n+S
\end{equation}\label{res3}\tag{5}
$$

The general term in the expansion of
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(1+x+x^2+...+x^p)^n\times\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2}
&=\left(\frac{1-x^{p+1}}{1-x}\right)^n\times\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2}\\
&=x^2(1-x^{p+1})^n(1-x)^{-(2+n)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{res}$$

If you haven't noticed where I'm going at this point, this is what I'm trying to do: to equate the co-efficients of $x^0$ on LHS and RHS of multiplying $\eqref{given}$ and $\eqref{res2}$ with the hope of calculating $S$.

But the problem here is,

1. The binomial expansion of $\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2}$ is valid only for $x>1$
2. From $\eqref{res}$, it is clear that LHS of $\eqref{given}\times\eqref{res2}$ has no term independent of $x$ and its powers.

Help please!!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, either combinatorially interpret $a_i$ or through formulas for multinomial expansion, that $a_i=a_{pn-i}$. Therefore

$$S=a_1+2a_2+...+pna_{pn}=\frac{1}{2}pn(a_1+\cdots+a_{pn})=\frac{1}{2}pn(p+1)^n$$

Comment: How do you combinatorially interpret $a_i$ and how did you come up with $a_i=a_{pn-i}$

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa Using the expansion formula definitely works; Combinatorially $a_i$ is the number of ways of distributing $i$ apples into $n$ baskets, with the number of objects in each basket $\leq p$. This is the same as distributing $pn-i$ bananas into $n$ baskets with the same constraint, and then fill each basket with apples so that there's $p$ fruits in each basket, then taking away all the bananas. Look up "generating functions". Hope it helps!

Comment: I think I need some time to wrap my head around what you've mentioned :|